# Database couldn't select

Tags: php, sql-server, database, select

In 2 lines of my php code ...

```
$link = mssql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);



if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($DB_NAME, $link)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database!');
}
```

$link connection is established, however, the DB selection not possible.. it says .. "The page isnt working"
HTTP ERROR 500

I tried the following code also -

```
if(!$this->_connection)
{
die('<font color="red">Error: Unable to connect to database host.</font>');
}
```

Connection works, however, the following code also results the same error

```
$this->_dbselect = mssql_select_db(DB_NAME, _connection);

if(!$this->_dbselect)
{
    die('<font color="red">Error: Unable to select database.</font>');
}
```

my database name is correct .. waiting for reply...

Regards,

Comment: First check your server's error log if you're getting *HTTP ERROR 500*

Comment: Where should i check it, using mylittleadmin tool to handle database

Comment: Error found in LOG it says "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$link' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\Inetpub\vhosts\nityalogic.com\httpdocs\register.php on line 61"

Comment: Line 61 means                                                                                                  .                                                                                                                                                                                $link = mssql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);                                                                                             .                                                                                                                      in above code. Waiting....

Comment: So you say that the connect is working, but the connect row has error? Instead of waiting, maybe you should try to debug a little bit more...